# Fragment's HOME icon not caught in Activity's onOptionsItemSelected()

Tags: android, android-fragments, event-handling, back

I am calling this `MainActivity` function from inside my fragment

```
public synchronized void setToolbarTitle(String title) {
        if(toolbarTitle !=null) {
            toolbarTitle.setText(title);
        }

        if(title.contains("Dashboard")) {
            drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
            toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        } else if(!title.contains("Dashboard")) {
            drawer.removeDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }
    }
```

Now, if I pass any title except "Dashboard", it shows a home indicator as expected. However, clicking that indicator does nothing. I want it to emulate `onBackPressed()`.

My `onOptionsItemSelected` is as follows

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Log.i("Here","Here");
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    } if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    } if (id == R.id.homeAsUp) {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this in onCreateView method of your fragment

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```